# Why do I get a "video system not initialized" error with my code?

Tags: pygame, python-3.5

I'm new to using pygame.
When I run the following code and try to close the pygame window, I get the error:

> "pygame.display.flip()
>   pygame.error: video system not initialized"

Here's my code:

```
import pygame
import random
import sys

class main:
    def __init__(self, height = 600, width = 800):
        pygame.init()
        self.screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))
        self.screen.fill((0, 255, 255))
        try:
            while True:
                for event in pygame.event.get():
                    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                        pygame.quit()
                    pygame.display.flip()
        finally:
            pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = main()
```

Comment: Because you're still trying to execute that line.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams **which line** are you talking about?

Comment: The one he's getting the error on.

Comment: You already importet `sys`, so just call `sys.exit()` after calling `pygame.quit()`

Answer (score 0):

As [Ignacio already hinted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33753937/why-do-i-get-an-error-with-my-code/33754510#comment55275749_33753937), if you close the game, you will read an event that is `pygame.QUIT` in your loop but you misunderstand the effect of `pygame.quit()` it's not leaving the loop, so the next line `pygame.display.flip()` is called as if there were the game still running.

**You** should care for leaving the loop. Maybe by replacing `while True:` with something like `while playing:`, you can set `playing` to `False` after getting the `pygame.QUIT` event.